# Is there anyway to access the problems of a virtual file via IntelliJ's plugin APIs?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I'm trying to write an IntelliJ plugin, the plugin needs to get the content in the Problems tool window.

[image]

Or is there an API that I can use to get the errors of the current file and project?

Comment: You can try inspecting the source code for Problems tool window at https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/tree/a1d2ab6e021bdc7a11aa55146f6366e68554fb36/platform/lang-impl/src/com/intellij/analysis/problemsView

Comment: Or contact IntelliJ IDEA platform developers at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200366979-IntelliJ-IDEA-Open-API-and-Plugin-Development for help

Comment: Thank you, after checking the source code, I found that I can use `ProblemsCollector.getInstance(project).getFileProblems(virtualFile);` to get the problems of the current opened file. Would you like to post an answer and I'll accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ProblemsCollector.getInstance(project).getFileProblems(virtualFile);` - this method can be used

See the whole implementation of the Problems View here https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/tree/a1d2ab6e021bdc7a11aa55146f6366e68554fb36/platform/lang-impl/src/com/intellij/analysis/problemsView